# Csh eval statement?

Tags: string, eval, csh

I'm trying to understand how the eval statement works. Here's a snippet of code I'm looking at that I don't understand:

```
    eval `$SOME_DIR/util/dbget.pl \
          VARIABLE1 \
          VARIABLE2 \
          VARIABLE3 \
          VARIABLE4 `
```

Anyways my initial idea after some research is that eval just literally types in those strings in the command line, meaning it runs the .pl script, then... I'm not sure what it's doing with those variables. The comment above this code said "get a few parameters" but I'm not sure what that means.

Does eval 'VARIABLE' initialize the variable? This seems to be the case because after the eval the code goes on to use these variables as if they're now initialized (does if statement checks, etc).

I'm clearly new to this kind of scripting and just jumping into a large repository. Thanks for any help.

Comment: turn on shell debugging with `set -vx` (I think that is right for csh). Then you can see the values for variables at different steps of processing. Good luck.

Comment: Backticks are at the top-left of your keyboard, right next to the 1 key (usually). Good luck.

Comment: There's a serious bug in `csh` on Debian-based systems: `eval` always dies with a segmentation fault. It doesn't affect tcsh. `/bin/csh` may be either bsd-csh or tcsh. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=933057

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the backticks are replaced with the output of the command between them.

The `eval` takes that output and executes it as if typed.

In this case I assume the perl is printing out some variable assignments, like `set VARIABLE1=value1` or `setenv VARIABLE1 value1`.  In which case, after the above `eval`, you should have `$VARIABLE1` available to later csh code.

Just running the .pl script (which I assume is Perl) without the `eval` would not affect the environment of the csh process.  By using `eval`, you're giving the Perl code permission to modify that environment.

This means the Perl has to know that its output is intended for csh, btw.  In sh/bash the syntax of variable assignment is different.

**ETA** More attempted clarification:

If you do this:

```
$SOME_DIR/util/dbget.pl
```

You get a bunch of variable assignment statements printed to your screen.  This is not useful, and has no effect whatsoever on the actual variables in your shell.

If you do this:

```
echo `$SOME_DIR/util/dbget.pl`
```

You get the same result in a more roundabout fashion: instead of the perl code printing directly to your screen, it's printing into an expression that gets passed to the csh `echo` command, and then the `echo` is what does the actual printing to the screen.  That distinction is subtle, but important: the backticks take control away from the perl and put it back in the hands of the shell.  Once the shell has captured the output, it can store it in a variable, write it into a file, or do lots of other things with it that the Perl code doesn't have to be rewritten to deal with.  The Perl is still just printing.

If you do this:

```
eval `$SOME_DIR/util/dbget.pl`
```

Then what the shell does is execute the output of the Perl as if it were typed at the prompt.  This is very powerful.  It's also dangerous, because the surrounding program winds up executing code that the person who wrote that program has never seen.  So you have to trust the source of that code (in this case the perl script) not to produce anything damaging (intentinonally or otherwise).

Comment: Good explanation of back-tics and eval. Good luck to all.

Comment: yes, noticed that and edited my comment. Will remove this shortly ;-)

Comment: OK it makes sense that the perl script is setting the variables. But what exactly is the point of after that eval'ing the VARIABLE1? Is that what you have to do to make it available to the csh code? I think that's what your answer says but I don't really understand why.

Comment: THe perl code cannot say "hey, csh! set this variable to this value!"  There's no way for anything outside of csh itself to do that.  All the perl can do is print out csh statements that will, *if executed by csh*, have the desired result.  But that's still just text printed out by the perl; it doesn't *do* anything until executed.  The `eval` is what tells csh to execute the code printed out by the perl.

Answer (score 0):

Both `eval` and the backtick syntax are explained in the csh man page.

If you're on a Linux system, it's likely that `csh` is really `tcsh`, an enhanced version of the original `csh` C-shell.  These particular features are the same in both csh and tcsh.  The backtick syntax invokes what's called "command substitution".

Quoting the tcsh man page on my system (with some minor tweaks to avoid markdown's special treatment of the backtick character):

> **Command subsitution**
>
> Command substitution is shown by a command enclosed in [backticks]. The output
>   from such a command is normally broken into separate words at blanks,
>   tabs, and newlines, with null words being discarded; this text then
>   replaces the original string. Within double quotes ("), only
>   newlines force new words; blanks and tabs are preserved.
>
> In any case, the single final newline does not force a new word. Note
>   that it is thus possible for a command substitution to yield only part
>   of a word, even if the command outputs a complete line.

And:

> **eval** arg ...
>
> (As in sh(1).)  The arguments are read as input to the shell and the 
>   resulting command(s) executed in the context of the current shell.
>   This is usually used to execute commands generated as the result of
>   command or variable substi‐ tution, since parsing occurs before these
>   substitutions.  See tset(1) for an example of using eval.